# How to trim image with php?

Tags: php

This is my index.php file, i have uploaded and moved image from tmp folder to           image folder and it's working properly. but now i want to trim image on display, every picture should be display of same size, i have tried lots of way but it's not working.
Need for help!!

```
<?php
require_once('appvars.php');
include 'db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM gitarwar";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<strong>' . $row['Score'] . '</strong><br/>';
    echo '<strong>Name:</strong>' . $row['Name'] . '<br/>';
    echo '<strong>Datetime:</strong>' . $row['Datetime'] . '<br/>';
    echo '<img src="' .GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['Screenshot'] . '"  alt="Score image" />';
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: This is a css question and not necessarily php. Just set width and height to your liking either inline or in a css file

Comment: Or trim the image server-side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654449/with-php-gd-how-do-i-trim-an-image?rq=1

Comment: But actually i want to do with php not css

Comment: Show us some of the ways you have tried. It will help us to see what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar task before. My job was to check the image, and if it is smaller than my `$newWidth` or `$newHeight`, it added.

```
$imageUrl = [PATH OR URL TO YOUR IMAGE FILE];

$imageContent = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($imageContent);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);

$newwidth = 300;
$newheight = 300;

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagealphablending($output, false);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($output, 0, 0, $transparency);
imagesavealpha($output, true);

imagecopymerge($output, $im, ($width < 300 ? (300 - $width) / 2 : 0), ($height < 300 ? (300 - $height) / 2 : 0), 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);

//Show the image
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($output); //You can save it with another parameter what is a path
imagedestroy($output);
imagedestroy($im);
```

You need to change this line:

```
imagecopymerge($output, $im, ($width < 300 ? (300 - $width) / 2 : 0), ($height < 300 ? (300 - $height) / 2 : 0), 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);
```

to your size.

It's actually not exactly what you want, but it could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the image when uploading it, by using `imagecreatefrom(jpeg|png|gif)` function.

```
$file = "images/" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['images']['type'];
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $file)) {
        chmod($file, 0777);
        // check the type of image, you can do this for other types too, just change the imagecreatefrom function to the type you want to save the image as
        if ($type === 'image/jpeg') {
            $jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            $jpeg_width = imagesx($jpeg);
            $jpeg_height = imagesy($jpeg);
            $new_width = imagesx($jpeg) / 4;          // Fix the width of the thumb nail images, change the width of image here
            $new_height = imagesy($jpeg) / 4; // change the height of image here

            //new image
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $jpeg_width, $jpeg_height);
            imagejpeg($new_image, $thumb);
            chmod($thumb, 0777);
        }
    }
```